# correct configuration for apache and mod_python

Tags: python, apache2, mod-python, ubuntu-10.04

**hi all, how you must configure Apache 2.2 or mod_python?, to avoid the following error:**

MOD_PYTHON ERROR
ProcessId:      5399
Interpreter:    '127.0.1.1'
ServerName:     '127.0.1.1'
DocumentRoot:   '/var/www'
URI:            '/cgi-bin/wps/'
Location:       None
Directory:      '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/'
Filename:       '/usr/lib/cgi-bin/wps/'
PathInfo:       ''
Phase:          'PythonHandler'
Handler:        'pywps'
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1537, in HandlerDispatch
    default=default_handler, arg=req, silent=hlist.silent)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/importer.py", line 1206, in _process_target
    object = apache.resolve_object(module, object_str, arg, silent=silent)
  File "/usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/mod_python/apache.py", line 696, in resolve_object
    raise AttributeError, s
AttributeError: module '/usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/pywps/**init**.pyc' contains no 'handler'

**this is for a configuration (ubuntu (10.4)) for AMD64.
thanks for your answers**

Comment: it looks like you're missing some of the end of the error message.

Comment: Aside: I believe mod_python is no longer maintained. Last update listed here http://www.modpython.org/ was in January 2008. Perhaps mod_wsgi would suit your purposes.

Comment: Adam is right, `mod_python` is officially no longer maintained (the open-source-equivalent-of-EOL kind of "no longer maintained") and its creator has been recommending that people switch to `mod_wsgi` for some time now.

Comment: belongs to http://serverfault.com/

Answer (score 0):

In my case, changing

> PythonHandler pywps

to

> PythonHandler wps

in the *.htaccess* (or the apache configuration file) fixed the problem.

I think that the file *pywps.py* has been renamed to *wps.py*, and this gives problems, since the sample configuration file has been left with the old name.